# How to embed a preexisting VF page into a section of the Account Page?

Tags: visualforce, custom, page-layout, edit

I am taking over for a outsourced team that I have no contact with. I want to replicate something that they have already done but I cannot figure out how they did it. I want to take an existing VF page and insert it into a subsection of an Account Page. The 'associated contacts' section of the picture is the custom VF page that the other team embedded. I want to do this in another section below it. Any help on where to start? I have looked into the 'edit layout' and 'customize page' buttons but there doesn't seem to be a way to import a new VF page. See attached picture.

[image: Custom Contacts Section]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that page, that you want to add is using standartController of you object:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" id="pg"> or
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="yourCustomExtension">
```

Then go layout -> edit -> visualforce section -> add where you want -> save:

*HOC is name of mine page*

[image]

Comment: hum when I change it to standardController I am getting an error message "viewAllActivityNotesOnAccount does not exist" This is my controller name...

Comment: I should add that I know the controller does exist and it was working fine until I changed it to a standardController

Comment: How big is your page and extension? Can you share it or at least first line from page

Comment: the controller is 207 lines and the vf is 50 lines. The first line from the VF page is: 
`<apex:page standardController="viewAllActivityNotesOnAccount">
<style>
.container
{
   overflow:auto;  
   align:bottom;
   width:1550px;
}
</style>
<apex:form > ......`

and my class is: 
`public class viewAllActivityNotesOnAccount {.....`

Comment: try <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="viewAllActivityNotesOnAccount">

Comment: just so I understand, why was it not able to pick up the custom controller without calling the standard object first?

Comment: so your page works perfectly, but if you want to add it to layout, Salesforce should understand if page belongs to particular object

Comment: okay, thank you :)